# Nginx 301 redirect with wildcard

Tags: nginx, redirect, http-status-code-301, nginx-config

Need to create a nginx 301 redirect.

From: `/blog/some-article`
To: `/blog/article/some-article`

Current nginx configuration:

```
    location /blog/(.*)$ {
            rewrite ^/blog/(.*)$ ^/blog/article$1 redirect;
    }
```

Current configuration result:

This URL with multiple 301 redirects

```
/blog/article/article/article/article/article/article/article/article/article/article/article/article/article/article/article/article/article/article/some-article
```

How to configure this redirect properly?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try: `location ~ ^(/blog/)((?!article/).+)$ { return 302 $1article/$2; }`

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly, I just changed 302 to 301 because I need a 301 redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead assertion in the regular expression to avoid the redirection loop.

This needs to be done at the `location` level.

You can avoid using two regular expressions by using a `return` statement instead or the `rewrite`. `rewrite...redirect` is implemented as `return 302`, whereas a `rewrite...permanent` would be implemented as `return 301`.

For example:

```
location ~ ^(/blog/)((?!article/).+)$ {
    return 301 $1article/$2; 
}
```